# How to display row as dictionary from pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

Very new to pyspark.

I have 2 datasets, `Events` & `Gadget`. They look like so:

```
Events
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

`Gadgets`

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I can read and join the 2 dataframes by using like so and present only the needed columns in my last line:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType 
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,array_contains

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('PySpark Read CSV').getOrCreate()

# Reading csv file
events = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("events.csv")
events.printSchema()


gadgets = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("gadgets.csv")
gadgets.printSchema()


enrich = events.join(gadgets, events.deviceId == gadgets.ID).select(events["*"],gadgets["User"])
```

My assignment is asking that I present the data like so in the dictionary object:

Enrichment Tasks:

- Enrich the event object with user data provided by the device.
- Ensure the enriched event looks like the following:

```
{
    sessionId: string
    deviceId: string
    timestamp: timestamp
    type: emun(ADDED_TO_CART | APP_OPENED)
    total_price: 50.00
    user: string
}
```

I can handle the dtype changes and column name renaming that the assignment is asking for,  however how do I deliver my results in the dictionary format above?

I am not sure how I can even show my results if I used this line:

```
enrich.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [create_map()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.create_map.html) function to create (key, value) pair of each column and its value.

The `create_map` requires input in form (key1, value1, key2, value2, ...). For that, use [itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["sess1","dev1","2022-12-19","emun(ADDED_TO_CART | APP_OPENED)","50.00","usr1"],["sess2","dev2","2022-12-18","emun(ADDED_TO_CART | APP_OPENED)","100.00","usr2"]], schema=["sessionId","deviceId","timestamp","type","total_price","user"])

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import itertools

df = df.withColumn("map", \
                   F.create_map( \
                       list(itertools.chain( \
                           *((F.lit(x), F.col(x)) for x in df.columns) \
                       )) \
                   ))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---------+--------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|sessionId|deviceId|timestamp |type                            |total_price|user|map                                                                                                                                           |
+---------+--------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|sess1    |dev1    |2022-12-19|emun(ADDED_TO_CART | APP_OPENED)|50.00      |usr1|{sessionId -> sess1, deviceId -> dev1, timestamp -> 2022-12-19, type -> emun(ADDED_TO_CART | APP_OPENED), total_price -> 50.00, user -> usr1} |
|sess2    |dev2    |2022-12-18|emun(ADDED_TO_CART | APP_OPENED)|100.00     |usr2|{sessionId -> sess2, deviceId -> dev2, timestamp -> 2022-12-18, type -> emun(ADDED_TO_CART | APP_OPENED), total_price -> 100.00, user -> usr2}|
+---------+--------+----------+--------------------------------+-----------+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can also collect it as [json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html) using:

```py
df = df.withColumn("json", F.to_json("map"))
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need. Unrelated question, I am trying to write to csv from the last line. I keep getting error `AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support map<string,string> data type.`. Could you please help me write this data frame to csv?

Comment: I did not get it. How do you want to save JSON as CSV?

Comment: You can save it as JSON `df.select("json").repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").json(path)` or only JSON column as CSV `df.select("json").repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv(path)`.